# how to display linear layout only when keyboard is up?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to display a linear layout with some textviews in it only when my soft keyboard is up. When soft keyboard is hidden the layout also should gone.how can i do that?[image]
EDIT
PFB the picture. Like this i want to display those options only when keyboard is up.And these options will be hidden if there is not keyboard present.

Comment: You've 1,117Rep and you're asking a question like this, it looks weird. Review what you just ask and edit the question and add some code

Answer (score 0):

check visibility of software keyboard in Android

[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

Comment: I know to check the visibility of the keyboard.I want to pin my linear layout with softkeyboard when it is up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".Book_Group" 
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" 
 android:label="@string/title_activity_book__group"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
```

> ADD IT INTO MANIFIST FILE LIKE THIS